A clarifying question about duality from another question.
I really would have just asked this in comments but I have insufficient rep.
the question in focus is Relation between Fourier Transform Duality and other properties.
the answer uses $$\mathcal{F}\{it X(t)\}=-2\pi\frac{dx(-\nu)}{d\nu}\tag{1}$$
i just dont see how that negative sign comes here. if we are using the duality property which states $\mathcal{F}\left\{X(t)\right\} = 2\pi x(-\nu)$.
in other words, I think the equation in the answer should be $$\mathcal{F}\{it X(t)\}=2\pi\frac{dx(-\nu)}{d\nu}\tag{1}$$
please help me resolve this discrepancy.

@MattL. i believe it is your answer.
